# Is HostSNI the only available tcp route rule in traefik?

Tags: tcp, traefik

Reading https://docs.traefik.io/routing/routers/#rule_1 it seems that the only way to route bare tcp requests through traefik is the HostSNI rule, is this it? I mean, fair, TCP doesn't have much else to demultiplex on except for ports and options - even SNI isn't bare TCP, right?

Are there any future plans to include any other rules for tcp routing in traefik?

Comment: I was looking for the same Answer. For me it seems as well that there is only this rule. I whish there were more, but I agree the info (like host) is not available. Correct, SNI is with tls.